# Using SetEnv in Apache : where and how can I do that?

Tags: php, apache, setenv

I want to run locally an App I am developing. There are instructions about how to config that here : http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#working_locally in 2).
I am using PHP, so I will use Apache. I had already runned a PHP project thanks to WampServer, but I do not know and do not understand how it works really.

Now I want to use SetEnv to set the env vars for my local app’s VirtualHost, as described in the link above (for FB variables). But I do not know what I have to write :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /Users/adam/Sites/mycoolapp-dev
ServerName mycoolapp-dev.localhost
SetEnv FACEBOOK_APP_ID 964173273189
SetEnv FACEBOOK_SECRET dcd5d23d003d53cb2b68e01
</VirtualHost>
```

some file ?

Or use the setEnv instruction in cmd.exe, somewhere ?

I have not found further explanations, and so am completely lost.

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: This looks okay. What issues are you having? What is not working?

Comment: That should be added to your Apache configuration file. It can be found in your Apache installation directory and should be named either `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf`.

Comment: Just the two `SetEnv` lines may also be specified in the `.htaccess` per-directory config file. See also http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your app file are located inside **facebook-test-app** folder, you can make the following changes and then your app will work on the local development environment.

```
    DocumentRoot C:/server/www/test/facebook-test-app
    ServerName facebook-test-app.localhost
```

Comment: Hi Metin - I am currently also stuck doing this!  The tutorial tells you to create a "development app" on facebook but this has not folder on your hard drive, so how do I specify a DocumentRoot ?  Am I supposed to clone the app to hard drive using git?  I'm really sorry for bringing up an old post but I'm very stuck!:D

Comment: Yeap, you should clone the app to your local development environment. But honestly I don't remember the exact steps I followed to solve this problem. When I get back home to my windows computer, I'll have a look at it for you.